# Playing radiostreams using javax.media.Player vs. javazoom.jl.player.Player

Tags: java, audio, streaming

I am new to playing audio with Java. I have written code to play some radio streams.
I find that there are some streaming urls like http://fm939.wnyc.org/wnycfm. This has no port number and contains slashes. I am able to play this type of url only with  *javax.media.Player*.

There are other streaming urls that come with a port number and no slashes. For example, I have a url for National Public Radio 140.254.23.68:8000. I can play these types of url with  *javazoom.jl.player.Player* since this player takes a url string and a port number.

Can someone tell me a little more about the types of streams and how to use the above players correctly. For example, is it possible to play the stream http://fm939.wnyc.org/wnycfm with *javazoom.jl.player.Player* ? If so, how?
Any help will be much appreciated.

Addendum:

Sorry I didn't mean to say javazoom Player accepts a url. I am using the following code snippet to create a javazoom player. As you can see from the code, I am using SocketFactory createSocket method to create a connection. The createSocket method takes a url and port. I'd like to know how to play a url like http://fm939.wnyc.org/wnycfm, in other words, a url without an explicit port number.

see code snippet below-

```
response = null;
try {
    SocketFactory sf = SocketFactory.getDefault();
    connection = sf.createSocket(url,port);
    request = "GET / HTTP/1.1\n\n";
    outputStream = connection.getOutputStream();
    if(outputStream!=null) {
    outputStream.flush();
    byte[] b = null;
    try {b = request.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);}
    catch(NullPointerException npe) {..}

    if(b != null) {
    outputStream.write(b);
    outputStream.flush();
    response = connection.getInputStream();
    }
} catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

javazoom.jl.player.Player zoomPlayer = null;
if(response!=null) {
    try {zoomPlayer = new javazoom.jl.player.Player(response);
    } catch (JavaLayerException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
}
return zoomPlayer;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"A URL can optionally specify a "port"".

so you can set the port.

I dont see where javazoom.jl.player.Player uses a url - maybe a newer version.

But in any case see the document for URL. One of the constructors says

```
URL(String protocol, String host, int port, String file, URLStreamHandler handler)

Creates a URL object from the specified protocol, host, port number, file, and handler.
```

The jmf player can be considered more stable. and documented.

javazoom.jl.player.Player is one line.

--

In fact I can play both streams with regular javax.sound procedures.

--

The way to get the url stream is this:

```
  String u="http://140.254.23.68:8000";
  URL url=new URL(u);
  URLConnection uc = new URL(u).openConnection();
  InputStream is=(InputStream)uc.getInputStream();
```

Comment: Could you clarify your response a bit? First of all, when I say url, I use the term in a generic sense to mean whatever you type in the url box on a browser. Can you tell me how to you call javazoom.jl.player.Player  to play the radio stream  http://fm939.wnyc.org/wnycfm ?  Also, not sure what you meant by your last sentence- "javazoom.jl.player.Player is one line".  Thanks.

Comment: I dont see anything like javazoom.jl.player.Player(url) ; can you point me to that web page of the documentaion of this class?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to say that javazoom player accepts a url. Please see my  addendum to my original post above. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @gpasch. I finally got it working with your help.